# How can I use and launch an exe file inside my c++ program?

Tags: c++, exe

I want to use an .exe file inside my c++ program. I reviewed and checked these functions (system - ShellExecute - CreateProcess) to achieve this goal, but I found them useless because I need the output of that .exe file inside my program for further processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CreateProcess can be used to pipe the output from the created program back to the creator. MSDN even has sample code to do exactly this: [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think you do want `CreatProcess`.  You can get the STDIN / STDOUT:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you should use the "Process.standardOutput" to read the result of an .exe.

Here is the link on MSDN, there is plenty of explainations:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You could use one of those functions to execute your file and have it write the output to another file.  Then you just have to read that into your program.